# Laravel displaying three tables with relationships, one table connects the two other tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 tables;

```
 Sizes - columns: (id, height, width)
 Media - columns: (id, media, description)
 Price - columns: (id, size_id, media_id, price)
```

Every Size, has every record in Media table, but the price is determined by each individual size and media.

My objective is to display each size and media with its price like so;

```
8x10 - Media 1 - $20.00
8x10 - Media 2 - $24.00
8x10 - Media 3 - $30.00
8x12 - Media 1 - $24.00
8x12 - Media 2 - $28.00
8x12 - Media 3 - $32.00
```

What I have tried so far is in (Size model):

```
public function media() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Size', '\App\Prices');
}

public function prices() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Size', '\App\Prices');
}
```

Without using relationships, I could do it this way;

```
$s = Size::all();
    foreach ($s as $size) {
        $m = Media::all();
        foreach ($m as $media) {
            $p = Price::where('enlarge_size_id', '=' , $size['id'])->where('enlarge_media_id', '=', $media['id'])->first();
            echo $size['height'] . 'x' . $size['width'] . ' -> ' . $media['media'] . ': $' . $p['price'] . '<br />';
        }
    }
```

Is this possible with relationships in Laravel? I am just looking for a cleaner method, to view, update, and add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case you should use many-to-many relation

first define Size model with many to many relations to media table:

```
class Size extends Model
{
    public function media() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Media::class ,'Price', 'size_id', 'media_id')->withPivot('price');
    }

}
```

then define Media Model for inverse of the relationship to size table:

```
class Media extends Model
{
    public function sizes() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class ,'Price', 'media_id', 'size_id')->withPivot('price');
    }

}
```

if you want to access to price column in pivot table you can use pivot prop in your related model for example :

```
   $sizes=Size:with('media')->first();
    foreach ($sizes->media as $media){
       $price=$media->pivot->price
    }
```